# ListWidget insertItems() менять элементы местами

Tags: c++, qt, виджет

Привет всем! Как реализовать данную задачу?

**Вот задача:** У нас есть ListWidget  заполняем элементы так QList `<QString> list; list << "1" << "2";` и тд. Таких элементов у нас штук 20. Хочу их перемещать на любую позицию интерактивно.

Есть 2 способа решения задачи:

1. Жмем мышью на 3 элемент и перетаскиваем его на позицию номер один. Было 1,2,3 стало 3,1,2 что то типо dragn drop в listWidget. Как это реализовать?
2. Справа от ListWidget делаем две кнопки которые перемещают выбранный элемент на который мы нажали вверх или вниз. И все так же было 1,2,3 кликаем на элемент 3 и жмем на кнопку "переместить на один элемент вверх" получается 1,3,2 кликаем еще получаем 3,1,2.

Так вот вопрос как сделать первый вариант и второй с сохранением данных позиций после перетаскивания в QList?

Comment: а ваши примеры реализации можно увидеть???

Comment: Создаешь класс с ui, пихаешь в ui listWidget далее в конструкторе cpp файла создаешь QStringList list; пушишь туда элементы list << "1" << "2" << "3"; вставляем это в виджет ui->listWidget->addItems(list); далее делаем dragn/drop этой строчкой ui->listWidget->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);  Все пашет, но как сохранить свои позиции элементов при перетаскивания в сам QStringList?

Comment: сохранять можно в сетинги при нажатии, и читать из них же

Answer (score 2):

Второй вариант можно реализовать обычным обменом строк для подъема вверх примерно так:

```
void MainWindow::on_UpButton_clicked()
{
    int currRow = ui->listWidget->currentRow();
    if(currRow > 0){
        QListWidgetItem tmp = *(ui->listWidget->currentItem());
        int upRow = currRow - 1;

        *(ui->listWidget->item(currRow)) = *(ui->listWidget->item(upRow));
        *(ui->listWidget->item(upRow)) = tmp;
    }

    lst.swap(currRow, upRow); // lst - наш лист
}
```

Для спуска элемента аналогично, только индекс вместо верхнего брать нижний, и проверять, чтоб текущий элемент был выше последнего.

Comment: Спасибо, идею понял. А как быть с drag/drop  ?  К примеру то, что мы в listWidget наменяли перетаскиваниями с помощью dragn/drop  считать это с ui->listWidget как то? и записать снова в QStringList.

Answer (score 0):

Все сделал, спасибо Shadasviar за идею.

**1) C Drag/Drop**

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void check();

private:
    QList<QString> list;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    list << "test1" << "test2" << "test3";
    ui->listWidget->addItems(list);

    ui->listWidget->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);

    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(check()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::check()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.count(); i++)
    {
        list[i] = ui->listWidget->item(i)->text();
        qDebug() << list[i];
    }
}
```

**2) Через кнопки вверх/вниз**

```
#ifndef CHOICEREPORTING_H
#define CHOICEREPORTING_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QListWidgetItem>

namespace Ui {
    class ChoiceReporting;
}

class ChoiceReporting : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ChoiceReporting(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ChoiceReporting();

    Ui::ChoiceReporting *ui;
public slots:
    void upList();
    void downList();

private:
    QList<QString> lst;
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "choicereporting.h"
#include "ui_choicereporting.h"
#include <QDebug>

ChoiceReporting::ChoiceReporting(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ChoiceReporting)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    lst << "test1" << "test2" << "test3";
    ui->listWidget->addItems(lst);

    connect(this->ui->pushButton_Up, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(upList()));
    connect(this->ui->pushButton_Down, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(downList()));
}

ChoiceReporting::~ChoiceReporting()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ChoiceReporting::upList()
{
    int currRow = ui->listWidget_Choice->currentRow();
    if(currRow >0 )
    {
        int upRow = currRow - 1;

        QListWidgetItem tmp = *(ui->listWidget_Choice->currentItem());

        *(ui->listWidget_Choice->item(currRow)) = *(ui->listWidget_Choice->item(upRow));
        *(ui->listWidget_Choice->item(upRow)) = tmp;

        lst.swap(upRow, currRow);
        ui->listWidget_Choice->setCurrentItem(ui->listWidget_Choice->item(upRow));
    }
}

void ChoiceReporting::downList()
{
    int currRow = ui->listWidget_Choice->currentRow();
    if(currRow < lst.count() - 1)
    {
        int downRow = currRow + 1;
        QListWidgetItem tmp = *(ui->listWidget_Choice->currentItem());


        *(ui->listWidget_Choice->item(currRow)) = *(ui->listWidget_Choice->item(downRow));
        *(ui->listWidget_Choice->item(downRow)) = tmp;

        lst.swap(currRow, downRow);
        ui->listWidget_Choice->setCurrentItem(ui->listWidget_Choice->item(downRow));
    }
}
```